# Partition and cluster by in Spark Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible for us to partition by a column and then cluster by another column in Spark?

In my example I have a `month` column and a `cust_id` column in a table with millions of rows. Can I say when I save the DataFrame to a hive table to partition the table based on month and cluster by `cust_id` into 50 files?

Ignoring the clustering by `cust_id`, there are three different options here

```
df.write.partitionBy("month").saveAsTable("tbl")
df.repartition(100).write.partitionBy("month").saveAsTable("tbl")
df.repartition("month").write.saveAsTable("tbl")
```

The first case and the last case are similar in what Spark does but I assume it just write the data differently in Hive(folders as opposed to files for each month).

In the second option, the repartition is undone by the `partitionBy` isnt it?

How can I avoid this at least?

Is it even possible to say repartition by a high cardinality column by specifying a number of buckets in Spark?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible for us to partition by a column and then cluster by another column in Spark?

It is, possible but `repartition` won't help you here.

```
df.write
  .partitionBy("month")
  .clusterBy(50, "id")
  .saveAsTable("tbl")
```

which is equivalent:

```
CREATE TABLE users_bucketed_and_partitioned(
 month T,
 id U
) USING parquet 
PARTITIONED BY (month)
CLUSTERED BY(id) INTO 50 BUCKETS;
```

Please rememeber that it is not Hive compatible, and seems to Have so unexpected performance implications.

Comment: Which version of spark is this available on? I am using spark 2.1 and cant find it on pyspark. Is this only on scala?

Error: 'DataFrameWriter' object has no attribute 'clusterBy'

Comment: In Python since 2.3 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16931) but it is easy to patch (check PR for implementation) and you can always use `SQL` (`spark.sql(...)`) if you don't want to patch.

Comment: I can see the bucketBy API is available in scala since 2.1 and can use that but I am curious how this can be done in spark.sql?

Do you mean by spliting the creation and insertion in steps in two and do it manually just like in SQL?

Comment: `df.createOrReplaceTempView("a_view")` and then `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT * FROM a_view`

Comment: Just a comment, the cluster by method on spark is a little messed up. It creates thousands of files for large flows because each executor spawns n number files (one for each bucket) so you could end up with n*exec_count number of files in the end.

Comment: This DataFrameWriter class don't have the function clusterBy(), but has the function bucketBy().

Answer (score 1):

Just to let other people who dont want to patch or write SQL insert statements know, but using a `repartition` and then a `partitionBy` on a dataframe actually works as I wanted it to and not how I expected it to.

Meaning, it first partitions by the key and then repartitions to the number.

Example:

```
df.repartition(100).write.partitionBy("month").saveAsTable("tbl")
```

produces 100 files of roughly equal size inside every partition where there is one folder(partition) created for each distinct value of month in the resulting table on hive.